# Prevent multiple card for collapsing React and MUI5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I need to create a page with recipes and every recipe will be in a Material Ui Card component. My problem is that everytime I collapse one of the cards, all the cards are collapsing. I need to prevent this. Can someone, please, explain how can I do this?
Here is my code so far.

RecipeCard.jsx:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import Card from "@mui/material/Card";
import CardHeader from "@mui/material/CardHeader";
import CardMedia from "@mui/material/CardMedia";
import CardContent from "@mui/material/CardContent";
import CardActions from "@mui/material/CardActions";
import Collapse from "@mui/material/Collapse";
import Avatar from "@mui/material/Avatar";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import { red } from "@mui/material/colors";
import FavoriteIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Favorite";
import ShareIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Share";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore";
import MoreVertIcon from "@mui/icons-material/MoreVert";

const ExpandMore = styled((props) => {
  const { expand, ...other } = props;
  return <IconButton {...other} />;
})(({ theme, expand }) => ({
  transform: !expand ? "rotate(0deg)" : "rotate(180deg)",
  marginLeft: "auto",
  transition: theme.transitions.create("transform", {
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.shortest,
  }),
}));

const RecipeCard = ({ id, title, subheader, image, description, recipe }) => {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);

  const handleExpandClick = () => {
    setExpanded(!expanded);
  };

  return (
    <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 345 }}>
      <CardHeader
        avatar={
          <Avatar sx={{ bgcolor: red[500] }} aria-label="recipe">
            R
          </Avatar>
        }
        action={
          <IconButton aria-label="settings">
            <MoreVertIcon />
          </IconButton>
        }
        title={title}
        subheader={subheader}
      />
      <CardMedia component="img" height="194" image={image} />
      <CardContent>
        <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
          {description}
        </Typography>
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions disableSpacing>
        <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites">
          <FavoriteIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton aria-label="share">
          <ShareIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <ExpandMore
          expand={expanded}
          onClick={handleExpandClick}
          aria-expanded={expanded}
          aria-label="show more"
        >
          <ExpandMoreIcon />
        </ExpandMore>
      </CardActions>
      <Collapse in={expanded} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
        <CardContent>
          <Typography paragraph>Method:</Typography>
          <Typography paragraph>{recipe}</Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </Collapse>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default RecipeCard;
```

Recipes.jsx:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import {
  Box,
  Card,
  CardActions,
  CardContent,
  Collapse,
  Button,
  Typography,
  useTheme,
  useMediaQuery,
} from "@mui/material";
import RecipeCard from "../components/RecipeCard";

const Recipes = () => {
  const isNonMobile = useMediaQuery("(min-width: 1000px)");

  const cards = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "Recipe 1",
      subheader: "test 1",
      image: "img1",
      description: "description 1",
      recipe: "recipe 1",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "Recipe 2",
      subheader: "test 2",
      image: "img2",
      description: "description 2",
      recipe: "recipe 2",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "Recipe 3",
      subheader: "test 3",
      image: "img3",
      description: "description 3",
      recipe: "recipe 3",
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      title: "Recipe 4",
      subheader: "test 4",
      image: "img4",
      description: "description 4",
      recipe: "recipe 4",
    },
  ];

  return (
    <Box
      mt="20px"
      display="grid"
      gridTemplateColumns="repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr))"
      justifyContent="space-between"
      rowGap="20px"
      columnGap="1.33%"
      sx={{
        "& > div": { gridColumn: isNonMobile ? undefined : "span 4" },
      }}
    >
      {cards.map((card) => (
        <RecipeCard
          key={card.id}
          id={card.id}
          title={card.title}
          subheader={card.subheader}
          image={card.image}
          description={card.description}
          recipe={card.recipe}
        />
      ))}
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Recipes;
```

Comment: Looks okay to me ... [does this sandbox behave the same as your local code](https://codesandbox.io/s/prevent-multiple-card-for-collapsing-react-and-mui5-ud3no5)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well...that's the behavior I want, but unfortunately it doesn't work. When I collapse one card, they all collapse...The sandbox doesn't behave the same on my local code.

Comment: I can't take too much credit, it's literally the same code that you posted! Are you sure it's the same code you're running locally? Usually at this point I start breaking things intentionally to make sure I'm not running a different version of my code.

Comment: yes, i'm very sure it's the same code...

Comment: if you line up all four in the same row and not the column, you will see the behavior I'm talking about. now it is curious that when they are aligned on the column, they have the desired behavior.

Comment: Oh ... I see it when the cards are side-by-side rather than in column layout. It's the Box grid layout – the element directly inside each grid square expands to fill the height. Wrapping each `<RecipeCard/>` in e.g. a `div` gives the desired behaviour.

Comment: thank you very much for your time and efforts! it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Collapse elements probably all have the same id value which is, if I'm guessing correctly what the collapse action do, it targets a specific id and if they have the same id all of them will collapse. You're passing an id value as prop to `RecipeCard` from `Recipes` but not using it anywhere.